# Add group product option to my custom product

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I created a new product type as `Simple product, group product` in woocommerce. Now I Want to add the feature `group product` in my product type. Anyway?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create attribute set In woo commerce.